# physics model simulation

Tags: opengl, physics, physics-engine

I am building a game for which I want to simulate certain rigid body dynamics.Could someone suggest me some engines which work on Ubuntu.Also as I have dont have much time to implement it,so it would be helpful if it is a easy one to work with.
I have some across one namely ODE.Am looking for others which would help me simulate collisions and angular movements.

Answer (score 2):

You haven't specified your environment and/or language bindings.

For 2d scenario Box2d is a very elegant choice and it has a lot of language bindings. Its quite easy to use. You just need to hookup your billboard/model/image(s) with its physics object and see the magic happen.

I don't know much about ODE. But have some experience with Bullet.[Bullet](http://bulletphysics.org) is faster then ODE. It also has a lot of advanced features i.e.  OpenCl cloth simulation.

For closed source [PhysX from Nvidia](http://www.geforce.com/Hardware/Technologies/physx) and [Havok from Intel](http://software.intel.com/sites/havok/en/). They are also free for commercial use.(there are constrains)

There are others but, above mentioned are most famous. What you want is Rigid body collision and angular movement. Only these 2 feature, shouldn't be very hard or time consuming to integrate. Go through their documentations. Most of them has individual doc part where is explains how to integrate.

Comment: well i am working on the NVidia GPU and am coding in opengl..would like to build my program on the ubuntu OS

Comment: well i think i would go with ODE for now, if that does not work then i would have to start with buller all over again